# Java generics parameters with base of the generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am wondering if there's an elegant solution for doing this in Java (besides the obvious one - of declaring a different/explicit function. Here is the code:

```
private static HashMap<String, Integer> nameStringIndexMap 
        = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
private static HashMap<Buffer, Integer> nameBufferIndexMap 
        = new HashMap<Buffer, Integer>();

// and a function
private static String newName(Object object, 
        HashMap<Object, Integer> nameIndexMap){
    ....
}
```

The problem is that I cannot pass *nameStringIndexMap* or *nameBufferIndexMap* parameters to the function. I don't have an idea about a more elegant solution beside doing another function which explicitly wants a *HashMap<String, Integer>* or *HashMap<Buffer, Integer>* parameter.

My question is:
Can this be made in a more elegant solution/using generics or something similar?

Thank you,

Iulian

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is here. Do you want to replicate your newName method for Buffers ?

Comment: I want to use the same function for both types. This is what I'm trying to achieve. There are some answer below helping me doing that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your function generic too:

```
private static <E extends Object> String newName(E object, 
        HashMap<E, Integer> nameIndexMap){
    ....
}
```

This bounds the two parameters of the function together, so for a `HashMap<String, Integer>` you can only pass `String` instances as first parameter. This may or may not be what you exactly want: if you only want to get elements from the map, Jon's solution is simpler, but if you want to add this object to the map, this one is the only choice.

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this:

```
private static String newName(Object object, 
        HashMap<? extends Object, Integer> nameIndexMap) {
    ....
}
```

or (as pointed out in the comments)

```
private static String newName(Object object, 
        HashMap<?, Integer> nameIndexMap) {
    ....
}
```

That will stop you from putting anything *into* the map, because you couldn't guarantee to get the key right - but you can get things *out* of the map and guarantee they'll be integers.

Note that this version doesn't make the method generic - which means it's simpler, but it *doesn't* provide the same type safety that Peter's version does, in that you can't guarantee that `object` is of the right type. Each approach has its pros and cons - use whatever is most appropriate based on the body of the method. (If you need to put an entry into the map, Peter's approach is definitely better.)

Comment: @newacct: True. I'll add that.

Comment: It is a good answer but the answer that serves my purpose is not this one. Thank you anyway for the answer