# Inconvertible types with nested generics

Tags: java, nested-generics

I looked at the other typecasting Java generics questions I'm still confused.

I have the following class hierarchy: `WeightedThing<T>` (just adds a weight to some random type) and a custom `Vector` class of which `WeightedVector` (no, `WeightedVector` is not just `WeightedThing<Vector>`) is a subclass.

I want to do nearest neighbor search and return a list of the closest vectors to a given query vector and their distances. For this, I defined a `search` method:

```
public List<WeightedThing<? extends Vector>> search(Vector, int limit) {...}
```

hoping I can do

```
List<WeightedThing<WeightedVector>> neighbors = (List<WeightedThing<WeightedVector>>)search(query, 1);
```

That doesn't work (IntelliJ doesn't mark it as an error, but compiling it with Sun's jdk7u10 for Mac OS X fails). Neither does calling the same function with `Vector`.
I can force it to compile by adding an upcast to `Object`, but that seems horrible.

The purpose of this is so I can search and add vectors of any type but if I know I only added WeightedVectors, I want to cast the results back to WeightedVectors.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522155/java-generics-parameters-with-base-of-the-generic-parameter

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but not really, see my comment on Ale E's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List of `WeightedThing<? extends Vector>` is not same as List of `WeightedThing<WeightedVector>`. To typecast it cast to wild char types that is `any collection` and then cast to specific type.

```
 List<WeightedThing<WeightedVector>> neighbors = (List<WeightedThing<WeightedVector>>)
                                                (List<?>)search(query, 1);
```

Comment: Not entirely happy with the answer, but that's more because of Java. :)

Answer (score 3):

In general it is not a good practice to use wild char types in the return type of a method.  Why don't you try to change the method signature as the following:

```
public <T extends Vector> List<WeightedThing<T>> search(T vector, int limit) {...}
```

Comment: That would work except that what I want is to be able to call `search` with a `Vector` but get back a list of `WeightedThing<WeightedVector>` since I added `WeightedVector`'s when calling `add`. I'm aware that this could conceivably cause invalid types, but what I want is the compiler to trust me that I'm doing the right thing.